# EXSLT template date:format-date works incorrectly after template date:add

Tags: xml, xslt, exslt

The following code

```
<td>
    <xsl:call-template name="date:add">
      <xsl:with-param name = "date-time"  select ="hml:LT" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "duration"   select = "'PT1H'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:call-template name="date:format-date">
      <xsl:with-param name = "date-time"  select ="hml:LT" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "pattern"   select = "'dd, MMM yyyy'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
```

outputs something like

```
<td>2011-01-18T07:27:24-00:00</td><td>18,  2011</td>
```

The second cell doesn't contain name of month (MMM in pattern)

At the same time code below works fine

```
 <td>
    <xsl:call-template name="date:format-date">
      <xsl:with-param name = "date-time"  select ="hml:LT" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "pattern"   select = "'dd, MMM yyyy'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
```

i.e. without date:add call before I get right date in output:

```
<td>18, Jan 2011</td>
```

Is it defect in EXSLT? Or I do something wrong?

I use EXSLT extensions to XSLT and all necessary templates are imported.

Here are full text of test files:
XSLT:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" 
    xmlns:hml="http://schemas.test/hml"
    extension-element-prefixes="date"
    exclude-result-prefixes = "hml"
    >

<xsl:import href="date.add.template.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="date.format-date.template.xsl" />
<xsl:import href="str.padding.template.xsl" />


<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:output method="html" indent="no" />

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <td>
    <xsl:call-template name="date:add">
      <xsl:with-param name = "date-time"  select ="hml:LT" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "duration"   select = "'PT1H'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
  <td>
    <xsl:call-template name="date:format-date">
      <xsl:with-param name = "date-time"  select ="hml:LT" />
      <xsl:with-param name = "pattern"   select = "'dd, MMM yyyy'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and XML:

```
<hml:LT xmlns:hml="http://schemas.test/hml">2011-01-19T02:16:06-00:00</hml:LT>
```

Comment: Which version of which XSLT processor do you use? And please provide some input sample allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: A added full test of input XML and XSLT. As for XSLT processor -- it is Apache Xalan, that is included into Websphere 5

Comment: BTW, I tested this code with java 6 (jdk_1.6.0_23) and its built processor -- the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your samples with Saxon 6.5.5 and xsltproc on Windows and the output both times is as follows:

```
<td>2011-01-19T03:16:06-00:00</td><td>19, Jan 2011</td>
```

So I don't think there is a problem with the templates for the EXSLT functions I took from http://www.exslt.org/, it looks more like a Xalan bug if you don't get the correct output with some version of Xalan.

Comment: bad news for me because I cannot change XSLT processor :(

Comment: As far as I know for the latest Websphere IBM has even developed an XSLT 2.0 processor so you might be able to switch to XSLT 2.0 and drop any EXSLT code. If you need to continue to use that built-in version of Xalan you currently have then all you could do is try to restructure the code in an attempt to avoid the problem but I am not sure where/how to start that attempt.

Comment: We use websphere 5, it is very old system and we cannot migrate at the moment. So I will try to rewrite this code in order to avoid the problem. Thanks for your check!